# Open a onclick= on blank with a <input type="button"

Tags: html, forms

Does anyone knows how to open, on a new window, the result of a input type="button" with onclick= ?

Here is my code, that opens the result on the same window:

```
<input type="button" name="enviar" id="enviar" class="roundShadow bkazul" value="ENVIAR" onclick="havingFunLearningMailValida(this.form.id)" />
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank You!

Comment: Thank you Suresh!...i am an absolute begginer!..would you please write the full code using window.open(url) for this <input type=“button” ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code of using window.open

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.yahoo.com')" value="Click" />
```

[**Fiddle Also**](http://jsfiddle.net/BGq89/)

Comment: onclick="javascript:window.open('havingFunLearningMailValida(this.form.id)')" doesn't work...??

Comment: it is a function. not a url.

Comment: show me the function you have used. so that i can give you the exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openTab()
{
window.open();// can insert any web links inside the open under the double quotes
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
open a new tab<input type="button" value="new tab" 

onclick="openTab()"/>

</body>
</html>
```